# SQLServer UnitTesting in Visual Studio - DROP DATABASE [MyDb]

Tags: sql-server, unit-testing, visual-studio-2019

I've set up a Unit Test project in Visual studio for my SQL Server project.

The test itself work, and the setup includes deploying that database. My problem is that I want to have a "clean slate" test, and every time I run a test, the data accumulates.

I tried manually calling a 'DROP DATABASE' from the SqlDatabaseSetup.cs, but it seems that I don't have a DataConnection at this point.

```
[TestClass()]
public class SqlDatabaseSetup
{

    [AssemblyInitialize()]
    public static void InitializeAssembly(TestContext ctx)
    {
        var q = ctx.DataConnection.CreateCommand();
        q.CommandText = "DROP DATABASE MyDb;";
        q.ExecuteNonQuery();

        // Setup the test database based on setting in the
        // configuration file
        SqlDatabaseTestClass.TestService.DeployDatabaseProject();
        SqlDatabaseTestClass.TestService.GenerateData();
    }

}
```

Is there anyway to indicate that the DB should be flushed first (without manually calling DELETE FROM XX for every table), or is there a way I can pass through a command to do that for me?

Comment: Have you tried connecting to the master database to create and drop your test database? Also if your schema, functions and stored procedures are pre-created in the model database then your newly created test database will be ready-to-go.

Comment: I am able to drop the master DB, but don't quite see why you're asking that? My problem isn't the structure of the DB, but rather the content.

Comment: That's not what I asked you to do.

Comment: You can't establish a connection to a database if it hasn't been created yet, nor can you drop the current database because of the open connection to it. What I said was connect to the master database to `create database [yourdatabase]` or to `drop database [yourdatabase]`.

Comment: @AlwaysLearning that was part of the problem, but not the problem yet. The problem was I didnt have a ctx.DataConnection yet, as it wasnt initialized. The moment I had that (from the context), I could drop the TestDb from the master db, which you pointed out. See my answer below.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution was as follows :

```
    [AssemblyInitialize()]
    public static void InitializeAssembly(TestContext ctx)
    {
        // Setup the test database based on setting in the
        // configuration file
        try
        {
            var conn = SqlDatabaseTestClass.TestService.OpenExecutionContext();
            var cmd = conn.Connection.CreateCommand();
            cmd.CommandText = "use master; ALTER DATABASE [MyTestDb] SET SINGLE_USER WITH ROLLBACK IMMEDIATE;DROP DATABASE MyTestDb;";
            cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
        }
        catch
        {

        }
        SqlDatabaseTestClass.TestService.DeployDatabaseProject();
        SqlDatabaseTestClass.TestService.GenerateData();
    }
```